# Android Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) loopback

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, loopback

I am running two applications on two Android phones (Android 11) that communicate over Bluetooth Low Energy. Now I need to install these two applications on the same phone, and make them communicate again over Bluetooth Low Energy.

Is it possible to create communication channel over Bluetooth Low Energy on the same device? To create Bluetooth Low Energy loopback? Similiar as it is with ethernet loopback.

Answer (score 1):

No it's not possible. A Bluetooth connection cannot be created to the same device. A Bluetooth radio can't even see its own advertisements when scanning. The reason is that a Bluetooth radio only performs one action at a time (tx or rx).

You would have to use another method for communicating between apps on the same device. One example is to use a Service with an aidl interface.